# How to select the best .class file from a folder?

Tags: java

I have one application for handling math operator .
My app has an interface Operator like so:

```
public interface Operator
{
    double calculate(double firstNumber,double secondNumber);
    String getSign();
}
```

I have 4 class that implement this operator like so:

```
public class Plus implements Operator
{   
    public double calculate(double firstNumber,double secondNumber)
    {
        return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }

    public String getOperator() 
    {
        return "+";
    }
}
public class Minus implements Operator
{   
    public double calculate(double firstNumber,double secondNumber)
    {
        return firstNumber - secondNumber;
    }

    public String getOperator() 
    {
        return "-";
    }
}
```

And so on...

I am compiling the classes and put .class file in a folder("myfolder")  .
Now in my main program(main app is another folder) I get type of the operator from user and according to this operator I want to choose from .class file the correct one but I don't know How to do this  .
Can anyone help me  ?

Comment: I think the short answer is don't.  Instead, create a `List` or array containing an instance of each operator and then use the `getOperator` method to find the appropriate instance. You could make the lookup more efficient if you used a `Map` of some kind

Comment: I know .I should implement this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't.
Why?
Using reflection will cost down performance.

Suggest:

```
final String OP_PLUS = "+";
final String OP_MINUS = "-";

List<Operator> listOperator = new List<>(){ new Plus(), new Minus() };

Operator getOperator(String inputOperator) throws NotSupportedException
{
    for(Operator op : listOperator)
        if(op.getOperator().equals(inputOperator))
            return op;
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Using:

```
Operator op = getOperator(OP_PLUS);
double result = op.calculate(d1, d2);
```

---

***In case of you have to do by this way*** (teacher tell you, etc....), you can use **Java relection**.
Read about java reflection first or this thread http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/methods.html
Following is the answer for you:

```
String requiredOperator =... // input

File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");
URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

// Create a new class loader with the directory
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

// Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
// the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
// Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass"); <= how to load a class
Class[] classes; // load your classes: Plus.class, Minus.class into this array
classes = new Class[]{ cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.Plus"), cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.Minus") };
Method method;
Object instance;
String identifier;
for(Class cls : classes)
{
    instance = cls.newInstance();
    method = cls.getMethod("getOperator", null); // method getOperator of Operator interface does not have any parameter
    identifier = (String)method.invoke(instance, null);
    if(identifier.equals(requiredOperator))
    {
        method = cls.getMethod("calculate", new Class[] { double.class, double.class } ); // two params are double
        return (double)method.invoke(instance, double1, double2);
    }
}
```

I did not test the code but that's the way for you

Comment: I should keep .class file in a folder and selet from .class files

Comment: Sorry why did u put this statment as a comment : // Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");

Comment: Because that's example how to load a Class using class name, and I use it after that, without comment

Comment: Is com.company the package name? If I don't have package i should just say "Plus" For Example?

Comment: Sorry Can we dynamically get the myclasses folder path in this prograam?

Comment: What ever if you can get Url to be used by UrlClassLoader

Comment: Sorry I have a question  . in the above code this part classes = new Class[]{ cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.Plus"), cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.Minus") }; dose not work dynamically if we put another .class file to our folder app stop working. we should load all class dynamically then check if they implement operator invoke their methods  . Do you have an idea?

Comment: Actualy, I did not code reflection before, my answer based on my knowleage about reflection, so you have to resolve it your self, sorry